# JAXB unmarshals Null elements to objects in array of arrays of objects

Tags: java, arrays, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I am using JAXB to save objects of an java application as XML files. But I have the problem that JAXB is unmarshalling null elements in the XML to Objects in Java when the null values are in an array of arrays. With a simple array, nulls are marshalled and unmarshalled again as nulls without problem.

I made an example with anymals in a Zoo, where the animals are in an array of arrays.

Class Animal:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Dog.class,Cat.class})
public class Animal {

    private String name = "";

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Animal is extended by the classes "Dog" and "Cat". Both have on extra Value (favoriteFood for Cat and favoriteToy for Dog).

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Dog extends Animal {
    private String favoriteFood = null;

    public String getFavoriteFood() {
        return favoriteFood;
    }

    public void setFavoriteFood(String favoriteFood) {
        this.favoriteFood = favoriteFood;
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
public class Cat extends Animal {
    private String favoritToy = null;

    public String getFavoritToy() {
        return favoritToy;
    }

    public void setFavoritToy(String favoritToy) {
        this.favoritToy = favoritToy;
    }
}
```

This is my class Zoo with the array of arrays of animals:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Zoo {
    private Animal[][] animals = null;
    private String name = null;

    public Animal[][] getAnimals() {
        return animals;
    }

    public void setAnimals(Animal[][] animals) {
        this.animals = animals;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void showNulls(){
        for(int i = 0; i<this.animals.length; i++){
            Animal[] row = this.animals[i];
            for(int j = 0; j<row.length; j++){
                if(row[j] == null){
                    System.out.println("Value at "+i+"/"+j+" is null");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Class for Testing:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Zoo myZoo = new Zoo();
        myZoo.setName("MyZoo");

        Cat myCat = new Cat();
        myCat.setName("Susi");
        myCat.setFavoritToy("Ball");

        Dog myDog = new Dog();
        myDog.setName("Brutus");
        myDog.setFavoriteFood("Meat");

        Animal[][] animals = new Animal[1][3];  
        animals[0][0] = myCat;
        animals[0][1] = null;
        animals[0][2] = myDog;
        myZoo.setAnimals(animals);
        myZoo.showNulls();

        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        File zooFile = new File("Zoo.xml");
        JAXB.marshal(myZoo, zooFile);
        System.out.println("Saved Zoo");

        System.out.println("------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Loaded Zoo");
        Zoo loadedZoo = JAXB.unmarshal(zooFile, Zoo.class);
        loadedZoo.showNulls();
        File zooFile2 = new File("Zoo2.xml");
        JAXB.marshal(loadedZoo, zooFile2);
        System.out.println("Saved Zoo2");
    }
}
```

The first xml looks like expected with a Null value:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<zoo>
  <animals>
       <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="cat">
           <name>Susi</name>
           <favoritToy>Ball</favoritToy>
       </item>
       <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
       <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="dog">
           <name>Brutus</name>
          <favoriteFood>Meat</favoriteFood>
      </item>
 </animals>
 <name>MyZoo</name>
</zoo>
```

But after unmarshalling, the Output shows, there is no Null value anymore:

```
Value at 0/1 is null
------------------------------
Saved Zoo
------------------------------
Loaded Zoo
Saved Zoo2
```

And the new xml now has an Animal element, where the null value was:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<zoo>
    <animals>
        <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="cat">
           <name>Susi</name>
           <favoritToy>Ball</favoritToy>
      </item>
       <item>
          <name></name>
      </item>
     <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="dog">
            <name>Brutus</name>
            <favoriteFood>Meat</favoriteFood>
       </item>
   </animals>
   <name>MyZoo</name>
</zoo>
```

Also, if I would make the Animal class abstract, there would be an error, because JAXB can't create the Animal for the null value then.

The only way I found to get this working somehow, was with an XMLAdapter that uses additional classes with an array of row objects. The row objects then contained the animals. But that is very cumbersome.
I would think there has to be an easier way to get the xml-null values unmarshalled as null values in the objects. Especially, since it works with one dimensional arrays.

If anyone knows a better way, how I can achieve that JAXB keeps the null values on unmarshalling, it would be great.